# SELECT query with "WHERE" clause does not return values in my jsp table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

Am trying to retrieve records from a database.Connection to database is verified on eclipse, but no information is updated on the jsp table. Am using a servlet class for dispatching, a java class for database replication (model) and jsp (view) that displays the table.

Here is MyUtils.DbAcess class containing the "forRecipient" method`

```
   package myPackage.Utils;

   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

   import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

   import java.sql.Connection;

   import myPackage.beans.MatchTable;
   import myPackage.beans.PhedUser;
   import myPackage.beans.UserAccount;

   public class DbAcess {

    .
    .
    .


    public static MatchTable forRecipient(Connection conn, String 
    recipient) throws SQLException  {
    String  query   =   "SELECT payer, payerPhone, payerEmail FROM 
    match_table WHERE recipientAccName=?;";

    PreparedStatement   ps  =   conn.prepareStatement(query);

    ps.setString(1, recipient);

    ResultSet rs    =   ps.executeQuery();
    List    <MatchTable>     list   =   new ArrayList<MatchTable>();

    while(rs.next())    {
        String  payer   =   rs.getString("payer");
        String  payerPhone  =   rs.getString("payerPhone");
        String  payerEmail  =   rs.getString("payerEmail");


        MatchTable  payerDetails    =   new MatchTable();

        payerDetails.setPayer(payer);
        payerDetails.setPayerPhone(payerPhone);
        payerDetails.setPayerEmail(payerEmail);
        list.add(payerDetails);
    }
return  list;

}
```

This is my database model which is the MatchTable.java

```
   package myPackage.beans;

   import java.io.Serializable;

   public class MatchTable implements Serializable {


   private  String  payer, payerPhone, payerEmail, recipientAccName, 
   recipientBankName, recipientAccNumber,  recipientPhone;

public MatchTable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public  MatchTable(String payer, String payerPhone, String payerEmail)  {
    this.payer  =   payer;
    this.payerPhone =   payerPhone;
    this.payerEmail =   payerEmail;
}

public MatchTable(String    recipientAccName, String recipientBankName, String recipientAccNumber, String recipientPhone)   {
    this.recipientAccName   =   recipientAccName;
    this.recipientBankName      =   recipientBankName;
    this.recipientAccNumber =   recipientAccNumber;
    this.recipientPhone =   recipientPhone;

}

public  String  getPayer()  {
    return payer;
}
public void setPayer        (String payer)  {
    this.payer  =   payer;
}

public String   getPayerPhone() {
    return payerPhone;
}
public void setPayerPhone(String payerPhone)    {
    this.payerPhone = payerPhone;
}

public String getPayerEmail()   {
    return payerEmail;
}
public void setPayerEmail(String payerEmail)    {
    this.payerEmail =   payerEmail;
}


public String getRecipientAccName() {
    return recipientAccName;
}
public void setRecipientAccName(String recipientAccName) {
    this.recipientAccName = recipientAccName;
}


public String getRecipientBankName() {
    return recipientBankName;
}
public void setRecipientBankName(String recipientBankName) {
    this.recipientBankName = recipientBankName;
}

public String getRecipientAccNumber()   {
    return recipientAccNumber;
}
public void setRecipientAccNumber(String    recipientAccNumber) {
    this.recipientAccNumber =   recipientAccNumber;
}

public String getRecipientPhone() {
    return recipientPhone;
}
public void setRecipientPhone(String recipientPhone) {
    this.recipientPhone = recipientPhone;
}

}
```

Then I call the "DbAcess.forRecipient" method in my Servlet class and request dispatch to view jsp file "ghTransactions" below;

```
package myPackage.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import myPackage.Utils.DbAcess;
import myPackage.Utils.SessionAccess;
import myPackage.beans.MatchTable;
import myPackage.beans.UserAccount;

/**
  * Servlet implementation class GHTransaction
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/ghTransactions"})
public class GHTransactionServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public GHTransactionServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    HttpSession session =   request.getSession();
    Connection conn =   SessionAccess.getStoredConnection(request);
    //Get stored match details
    //MatchTable    payerDetails    =   SessionAccess.getStoredMatchTable(session);

    String errorString  =   null;
    String payer = null;
    String  payerPhone = null;
    String  payerEmail  =   null;

    MatchTable Payer    =   new MatchTable(payer, payerPhone, payerEmail);
    //Get loggedInUser Details to retrieve user account name for query to match table database
    UserAccount loggedInUser    =   SessionAccess.getStoredLoggedInUser(session);
    String  recipientAccName    =   loggedInUser.getAccountName();
    try{
        DbAcess.forRecipient(conn, recipientAccName);
    } catch (SQLException e)    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        errorString =   e.getMessage();
    }
    request.setAttribute("user", loggedInUser.getUserName());
    request.setAttribute("payer", Payer);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher    =   request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/ghTransactionView.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

My stackTrace snapshot shows successful connection to the database

```
 Sat Apr 29 18:54:11 WAT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

However the view is not populated with the records even when there are matching details.

Below is the ghTransactionView.jsp file

```
  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <center>
    <h3>Payer Details</h3>
    <table style="width:100%; padding:6px;" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;Name</th>
            <th>&nbsp;Phone</th>
            <th>&nbsp;Email</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${payer }" var="payerDetails">
        <tr>
            <td>${payerDetails.payer }</td>
            <td>${payerDetails.payerPhone }</td>
            <td>${payerDetails.payerEmail }</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

I need assistance as to where I have gone wrong and why the records are not populated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not collect and pass the queried list to the JSP i.e., the data returned from `forRecipient` has not been used.

So you need to add the below code in your `GHTransactionServlet` `doGet()` method:

```
//Collect the returned list using a ref. variable
List<MatchTable> matchTableList =DbAcess.forRecipient(conn, recipientAccName);
//Now set the data to request scope so that JSP can access it
request.setAttribute("payer", matchTableList);
```

Also, the important point is that the `request` scope `matchTableList` object has been set with key as `payer` which is the same as the `items` attribute for the tag `c:forEach` inside JSP.